# JPA @Query with 'case when exists' does not work with Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a @Repository interface with the following method for checking IF database contains a record colliding (in business domain meaning) with the one 
I'm about to persist (I don't care about WHAT the colliding records are):

```
@Query("select case when exists (
            select me from MyEntity me where {my conditions regarding someParam here}
        ) then true else false end from MyEntity")
boolean findColliding(@Param("someParam") String someParam);
```

The table on which I run it is empty (PostgreSQL) therefore the **exists** subquery shouldn't find anything and I believe the whole method should return false as **case** states it can only return true if exists and false otherwise.

It returns null #facepalm

My query passes query syntax check on startup (no QuerySyntaxException) but throws exception when executed:

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract boolean findColliding(...)
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I take some other approach for my problem?

Hibernate 5.0.11.Final

Comment: Are you sure this is a hibernate problem and not a spring data problem? I haven't tried exactly that query, but I am pretty sure that I already got something like that working.

Comment: A comment on the structure of this query. It currently is a N^2 query. Instead of `select case ... (select ... from MyEntity ...) ... from MyEntity` it should be `select case ... (select ... from MyEntity ...) ... from dual`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPA 2.1 CASE expression [only supports scalar expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-case-expressions), not queries.

For more details, check out the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

If the DB supports this syntax, you need to use [a native SQL query](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/) instead.