# JPA provider Hibernate 5.4 and select case with subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does Hibernate 5.4.3 supports translating the following SQL query to Criteria Builder

```
select
 b1.id as id,
 b1.id2 as id2,
 b1.status as status,
 b1.status2 as status2,
 (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 from test.statuses a where a.id2 = b1.id and a.status = 'A') THEN 'TEST1'
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 from test.statuses a where a.id2 = b1.id and a.status = 'B') THEN 'TEST1'
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 from test.statuses a where a.id2 = b1.id and a.status = 'C') THEN 'TEST2'
      ELSE ''
END) as over_status,
 b1.test_ak as test_ak,
 b1.date_ack as date_ack,
 b1.xml_1 as name_1,
 b1.xml_2 as name_2
 from test2.stats b1
 order by b1.id asc limit 10000
```

NOTE: the query is not important in this question, only the case part and its position is important.

Also, I've found this answer

[JPA @Query with 'case when exists' does not work with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833498/jpa-query-with-case-when-exists-does-not-work-with-hibernate)

Which basically says, no. Just wanted to double check if something has improved regarding the *case* situation

Comment: no this is not supported. not why don't you simply try?

Comment: I've have tried to craft the query using criteria builder and after a while I came to a conclusion that this is not possible. Just to be sure that it is not me, but criteria builder, I thought it would be a good idea to consult stackoverflow before dropping it. Are there any alternatives that would not involve writing a raw SQL (trying to write a dynamic SQL for data filtering purposes). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: use https://jooq.org

Comment: To replace everything what was written with jooq seems to be very expensive. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: You don't have to replace everything. Just use jOOQ for the complicated queries